# How to execute, "Run Advertised Programs" with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I display all the available applications on the `"Run Advertised Programs"` using `PowerShell`.

```
$tpObject = Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\ccm\Policy\Machine\ActualConfig -Class CCM_SoftwareDistribution `
    | Select-Object -Property PKG_Name, PKG_PackageID
```

This part works fine.

My Question: How do I execute one of these apps using PowerShell.  I tried,

```
$tpObject.ExecuteProgram($ID, $PackageID,$true)
```

Where I Substituted the `$ID` and `$PackageID` for the values discovered in the first step. The code to execute the app gave me an error.  I think my syntax is incorrect.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

tks

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you receive?

Comment: Why do you ask questions when you don't intend to accept any answer in the last 10 questions? You didn't gather any reputation also from these question and IMO your behaviour is slightly asocial in this aspect.